# Hi I want to create two(or more) blogs in rails that share articles between them similar WordPress broadcast plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I don't have problems with creating the sites(blogs) and i looked at Pusher and Action Cable but i only see examples off real time posts to the same site. I'm interested of to different sites.

Comment: I'm not aware of any gem that will replicate the Wordpress Broadcast plugin for Rails. However it should not be too difficult to do in Rails. Are all the websites you want to post to under one Rails app or multiple Rails apps?

Comment: I want to do them individually but I'm open to suggestions, i'm also looking for rails multisite approach, what do you think is better

Comment: It's difficult to give any hard recommendations without understanding the whole context and it's beyond the scope of stack-overflow to really discuss this. Nevertheless, I guess the next question is, have you a chosen a Rails CMS gem for your websites? We have our own (https://github.com/brodjustice/semi_static/tree/rails_v5) that would be fairly easy to extend. The idea would be to use the Rails REST API to simply sync/copy the blogs between the websites  (each with it's own Rails app). Probably the biggest challenge would be authentication between the separate Rails apps.